# Flutter : screen orientation stay landscape after youtube fullscreen

Tags: flutter, youtube, fullscreen, video-player

I have flutter app used youtube_player_flutter 8.0.0 package for playing youtube video, I create this youtube player widget :

```
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

YoutubePlayerBuilder videoPlayer(video) {
  YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: video,
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: false, controlsVisibleAtStart: true));
  return YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
      builder: (context, player) {
        return player;
      });
}
```

and used it in a screen like this :

```
videoPlayer(currentDay[0]['link'])
```

the video is work fine, but when I switched to fullscreen the screen be landscape and stay at landsacpe also after I rotate the device.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the orientation of the full application with :

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft])
  .then((_) {
  runApp( const MyApp());
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to fix orientation

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Scaffold to WillPopScope , then in onWillPop method change orientation of device and return true ..

Example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async {
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  return true;
},child :Scaffold(..)
```

)